# Question about calling method inside custom IO operator in C++?

Tags: io, operators

I have the following code:

```
#include "iostream"
#include "conio.h"
using namespace std;
 class Student {
 private:
     int no;
 public:
     Student(){}
     int getNo() {
         return this->no;
     }
     friend istream& operator>>(istream& is, Student& s);
     friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Student& s);
 };
 ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Student& s){
     os << s.getNo(); // Error here
     return os;
}
int main()
{
    Student st;
    cin >> st;
    cout << st;
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

When compiling this code, the compiler produced the error message: "`error C2662: 'Student::getNo' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const Student' to 'Student &'`"

But if I made the `no` variable `public` and change the error line like: `os << s.no;` then things worked perfectly.
I do not understand why this happened.
Can anyone give me an explanation, please?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `s` is `const` in that method, but `Student::getNo()` isn't a `const` method. It needs to be `const`.

This is done by changing your code as follows:

```
int getNo() const {
    return this->no;
}
```

The `const` in this position means that this *entire method* does not change the contents of `this` when it is called.

Comment: That means I have to to: const int getNo()?? But it also did not work.

Comment: @ipkiss: I have updated Andrew's answer to show how to do that.